# I am having trouble using VBA to replace a row where is a condition is met to be replaced with a copied row from another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

We have a report, and I would like to create a visual break when a condition is met. Images and code I've tried below.

(Tried posting an image of my sheet, but received forbidden error message despite being under file size - so I will do my best to explain)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PauN3.jpg)

"Sheet 1" 
Columns (A:R) - Header
Rows (1:TBD) - Data

"Sheet 2"
Columns (A:Q)
Rows (1:1)

My apologies if any formatting or explanation is unclear this is my first post, and I'm newer to this. So if any clarification is needed please let me know.

What I am looking to do is have a row replaced if a condition is met. The end goal is to have the copied cells from Sheet 2 (Row 1) pasted into the sheet where applicable. In this instance it is a visual break whenever the report has a new client. In order to accomplish this I subtotaled the AccountName column (J) and it placed an AccountName Count in (I) and the actual count in (J) under the last record.

In Column (R) Then I placed the following code:

```
{=ISNUMBER(SEARCH("count",I2))}
```

I would like the cells from "Sheet 2" (A:R) to be copied and pasted into the "Sheet 1" (A:R) whenever R2's value is true as a result of the above formula.

I watched the following video and used it as the basis, but I am not having any luck. 
[Video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PauN3.jpg)
I used the code verbatim at the 9:36 mark

```
{Private Sub CopyText_Click()

a = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To a

    If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 3).Value = (Search("TRUE")) Then

        Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(i).Copy
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
        b = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(a + 1, 1).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate

    End If
Next

Application.CutCopyMode = False

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Select

End Sub}
```

In the above code

Comment: Please clarify, your question says you want to copy the header row from `Sheet2` to `Sheet1` when the formula in `Column R` is `TRUE` replacing the current row in `Sheet1`. While your code copies the header row in `Sheet1` when the formula in `ColumnC` is `TRUE` and pastes into `Sheet2` to the empty row after the last used row. You need to update your question to clarify what you are trying to accomplish. Your code should bear a resemblance to your description, and what error or issue you are encountering.

Comment: To post images, upload them to http://imgur.com and link to them.